# Puppet file_line in specific order

Tags: authentication, environment-variables, sh, puppet

Im trying to add three system hardening lines to /etc/profile:

```
TMOUT=43200
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
```

Of course those lines need to be in this specific order and I also have to expect files which are messed up and are in the wrong order.
**I can't use a template because there are hosts with custom profiles which can't be changed. So I have to be able to append those three lines**

So I wrote this in my manifest:

```
file_line { 'TMOUT':
  path     => '/etc/profile',
  ensure   => present,
  line     => 'TMOUT=43200',
  multiple => true,
  before   => 'readonly TMOUT',
  match    => '^TMOUT',
}
file_line { 'readonly TMOUT':
  path     => '/etc/profile',
  ensure   => present,
  line     => 'readonly TMOUT',
  multiple => true,
  before   => 'export TMOUT',
  after    => '^TMOUT=43200',
  match    => '^readonly TMOUT',
}
file_line { 'export TMOUT':
  path     => '/etc/profile',
  ensure   => present,
  line     => 'export TMOUT',
  multiple => true,
  after    => '^readonly TMOUT',
  match    => '^export TMOUT',
}
```

Puppet creates the lines in the correct order but when I edit the file and change the order it doesn't get corrected during a rerun e.g.

```
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT
TMOUT=43200
```

Did I make a mistake or do I have to switch to something else like Augeas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

You basically have three options: try to create ordered dependencies (which is not really the Puppet way), create compound statements, or use */etc/profile.d* if your distribution supports it. While there is no single "best" way to handle this, a compound statement or declaration is probably the simplest solution for you.

### Ordered Dependencies

Puppet doesn't guarantee ordering for most operations unless you explicitly declare dependencies. The following is untested, but may work for you.

```
file_line { 'set TMOUT':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/etc/profile',
  line   => 'TMOUT=43200',
  match  => '^TMOUT',
} ->
file_line { 'export TMOUT':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/etc/profile',
  line   => 'export TMOUT',
  after  => '^TMOUT=',
} ->
file_line { 'set TMOUT as readonly':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/etc/profile',
  line   => 'readonly TMOUT',
  after  => '^export TMOUT',
}
```

This should do what you want, but is more fragile than it needs to be. There are more robust options.

### Compound Statements and Variable Declarations

Most (if not all) Bourne-compatible shells should support compound statements, so you'd be better off skipping the ordering for a single atomic line operation. For example:

```
file_line { 'profile TMOUT':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/etc/profile',
  line   => 'TMOUT=43200; export TMOUT; readonly TMOUT',
  match  => '^TMOUT',
}
```

Better yet, use the shell's *declare* synax to do it all in one operation! For example:

```
file_line { 'profile TMOUT':
  ensure => present,
  path   => '/etc/profile',
  line   => 'declare -r -x TMOUT=43200',
  match  => '^TMOUT',
}
```

*NB: The readonly variable can still be assigned to in subshells that don't set the readonly attribute directly. This is just the way it works.*

### Place a File Into Profile.d

On distributions that support it, using */etc/profile.d* is almost always a better option than monkeying around in a monolithic script like */etc/profile*. It is also less likely to be clobbered by other scripts, system updates, and so forth. However, there are a few caveats, which I note below.

```
# Create your snippet in the /etc/profile.d directory.
file {'/etc/profile.d/tmout.sh':
  ensure => present,
  content => "TMOUT=43200\nexport TMOUT\nreadonly TMOUT",
} ->

# Remove the lines in /etc/profile if they exist.
file_line { 'profile TMOUT':
  ensure            => absent,
  path              => '/etc/profile',
  match             => 'TMOUT',
  match_for_absence => true,
  multiple          => true,
}
```

There are a number caveats to note here:

1. There's a subtle race condition (even with dependency chaining) because the changes are sequential rather than atomic. There may be a small window where TMOUT is defined in multiple places.
2. Because profile.d is vendor-specific, it may not be supported at all (and may not even exist) unless you configure it. Check your distribution documentation.
3. Again, because profile.d is vendor-specific, the order in which scripts in profile.d are sourced may vary. They are generally sourced after the main */etc/profile* script, and the existence of multiple scripts that set the same value can make the results non-deterministic.